# Difference Tool (Polygon) Not Working

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, differences, symmetric-difference

Okay so I'm using QGIS 2.10 (a couple of versions out of date, but shouldn't matter much, eh?) on Windows 7, and I can't figure out this supposedly a very basic geoprocessing tool DIFFERENCE.

I'm trying to use a small polygon to find the DIFFERENCE in a larger polygon that completely covers the smaller polygon, so the result should be the larger polygon minus the smaller polygon, and the shape would look like a donut or bagel, but every time the result comes back as empty.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I tried switching the layers and nothing worked either.

I mean, there's only 2 inputs and 1 output for this tool, how difficult could it be?

Comment: Are the spatial references of both datasets clearly defined and at least compatible (preferably the same)?

Comment: Yes they should be, both are converted from KML, and I've saved them as SHP files.
And they do overlap, the smaller one is completely inside the larger one.

Comment: Okay i saved the .shp files as MapInfo .tab files and the DIFFERENCE tool worked.
That's so weird though, I don't get why .shp files doesn't work.

Comment: The most likely cause is an incorrect ring orientation or self intersection in either or both shapefiles which is likely cleaned when converted to a TAB file.

Comment: Ring orientation? Self Intersection?
Uhm, interesting, not familiar with any of those terms.
Thanks though!
If you could explain, that would be nice.
But ya, either way, thanks for your response and interest in this issue.

Comment: Shapefiles contain features which are in this case polygons, which are made from rings (each continuous part is a ring), according to the spec the rings need to go clockwise for outsides and anti-clock for holes, if this is not the case it's called 'incorrect ring orientation'. Self intersection is where a polygon crosses itself, either the same ring or where a hole crosses into the outside. Both of these situations cause havoc with the geometry engine as inside/outside rules are broken where these are encountered.

Comment: I'd *strongly* recommend upgrading to a newer version - there's been many many bug fixes since 2.10 was released.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I saved the .shp files as MapInfo .tab files and the DIFFERENCE tool worked.

Although I have wonder why it doesn't work with .shp files.

Okay so the issue was identified up there by user Michael, this probably have something to do with the fact that I created the polygons in Google Earth and then saved them as KMLs, it was the quickest way by far to generate the accurate polygons that I needed.